# Tidal forces of radial geodesics in Schwarzschild spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, geodesics, tidal-effect

Let me start with the questions I have:

1. Since infinite tidal forces at the event horizon are meaningless, is this yet again a result of the choice of coordinates?
2. What exactly do we call the tidal force, if the parameter $s$ for the curve family established by $\varphi(\tau, s)$ in the following is arbitrary?

The Schwarzschild metric is of course given by
$$
  -\text{d} \tau^2 = -w(r) \text{d} t^2 + w(r)^{-1} \text{d} r^2 + r^2 \text{d} \theta^2 + r^2 \sin \theta \text{d} \varphi^2 \text{,}
$$
where $w(r) = 1 - 2 M / r$.
Since we are dealing with radial geodesics, we may neglect the angular part of the metric alltogether for the four velocities of particles falling freely.
On the one hand, we find for a massive particle that
$$
  \dot{r}^2 = \widetilde{E}^2 - w(r) \left( 1 + \frac{\widetilde{L}^2}{r^2} \right) = \widetilde{E}^2 - w(r)
$$
where $\widetilde{E} = E / m$ and $\widetilde{L} = L / m$ are constants along geodesic world lines due to the Killing vector fields $\partial_t$ and $\partial_\varphi$ and the dots indicate derivates w.r.t. the proper time $\tau$. For constant $\varphi$, we have $L = 0$.
Using the metric again, we can also extract
$$
  -1 = -\left( \frac{\text{d} \tau}{\text{d} \tau} \right)^2 = -w(r) \dot{t}^2 + w(r)^{-1} \dot{r}^2 = -w(r) \dot{t}^2 + \widetilde{E} w(r)^{-1} - 1
$$
and so we have $\dot{t}^2 = \widetilde{E} w(r)^{-2}$. Together the four velocity in Schwarzschild coordinates reads
$$
  \vec{u} = \frac{\text{d} x^\mu}{\text{d} \tau} \partial_\mu = (\dot{t}, \dot{r}, 0, 0) \text{.}
$$
Next, we parameterize the family of curves $x^\mu = (t(\tau), r(\tau), 0, \varphi(\tau, s))$ by, say $\varphi(\tau, s) = s$. Then the deviation vector between two neighbouring curves is given by
$$
  \vec{n} = \frac{\text{d} x^\mu(\tau, s)}{\text{d} s} = (0, 0, 0, 1)
$$
Putting all of it together, we compute the geodesic deviation or tidal force
$$
  \frac{\text{D}^2}{\text{D} \tau^2} n^\delta = {R^\delta}_{\alpha \beta \gamma} u^\alpha n^\beta u^\gamma = \left( -\frac{r \sin^2 \theta}{2 w(r)^2} \left[ \widetilde{E}^2 + \left( \widetilde{E}^2 - w(r) \right) w(r)^2 \right] w'(r) \partial_\varphi \right)^\delta \text{.}
$$
But this expression diverges at the event horizon. Is this again an artifact of Schwarzschild coordinates?

Comment: I'll rephrase the question, because if everything is correct I am still struggling with the interpretation.

Comment: Your final equation doesn’t make sense because the indices are unbalanced. You have a free index $\mu$ on the left, a free index $\delta$ in the middle, and no free index on the right.

Comment: Thanks, you're right! I corrected that now.

Comment: Since this question has been closed because it is homework-like or a check-my-work question, I condensed it to the actual questions I had about the result, which I consider to be on-topic. Is there anything I can do to have it re-opened, so these questions can be answered?